# PDF.js is randomly crashing the Google Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, compatibility, pdf.js

My problem may seem a bit vague (it is to me too), but here is my attempted explanation of it.

A few months ago, I implemented [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) in my web application. It was really useful, and I am using it for interactions with my clients.

Suddenly, last week, my clients reported to me "Aw, Snap" messages in Google Chrome on their PCs when they try to launch PDF.js. I have an iMac and two PCs at home, so I decided to test this out.

When I used Google Chrome on my iMac to launch PDF.js, I found it worked fine.

When I used Google Chrome on my first PC to launch PDF.js, I found it worked fine.

When I used Google Chrome on my second PC to launch PDF.js, even though it previously worked, it kept crashing and showing me "Aw, Snap" messages.

This was weird. I tried removing all the extensions, clearing the cache, clearing the LocalStorage, but nothing seemed to fix the problem.

I then realised, after some communication with my clients, launching PDF.js in Safari, Torch, Opera or Firefox on any operating system worked perfectly fine.

Why would this happen? I am using the web viewer in PDF.js. I also tried with the basic `hello world` example, but that broke as well (which I now find really weird), so I suspect there's something wrong with the rendering engine.

I also tried including the `compatibility.js` file after building the source, but with no avail.

Is there any known bug which causes Google Chrome tabs to crash?

Comment: See also https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333594

Comment: See also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4104

Comment: @RobW Yes, thanks Rob, I asked the PDF.js dev team, and they gave me that URL as well. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got it now.

From https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4104, I found the answer (thanks Rob and PDF.js dev team!). Take a look yourself!

I'm only posting this here so that anyone who stumbles upon this post with a similar problem can be helped (as this error took me quite a while to figure out).

Comment: We have [recently updated PDF.js with a work-around](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4104#issuecomment-32610314). Can you check whether you're still experiencing crashes with the latest version of PDF.js? If you're still experiencing crashes, please share the PDF file with the PDF.js team for debugging purposes (well, it's a browser bug, but we can at least check whether it still affects PDF.js).

Comment: The bug in Chromium (v8) has been fixed - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333594#c33.

Comment: @think please tell what exactly u did to fix the problem.i'm also facing this same issue.but after 2-3 pdf load.so i have to do somethong in my project or something else ?i'm using pdfjs 1.0.21 and latest google chrome 36.0.1985.125

Comment: @nichu09 So on the link I posted, gjuggler comments, stating that a previous version worked for him, and that was when it was all still working. What I ended up doing though was creating my own small PDF viewer with some Imagick in PHP and JavaScript canvas, and even though I couldn't select text, I still thought of it as being more stable than PDF.js, but check the revisions! Download the version mentioned, and maybe it works well for you!

Comment: @think123 I am facing the same issue and tried this https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4104 but even though am facing this issue .. Could u please guide me to resolve ..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case. We've tried the latest version of pdf.js from github, also tried Chrome 33 (stable) which should have their V8 fix included and it still crashes. Also, tried the pdf.js commit mentioned in github thread (4ce6cb8 - https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/commit/4ce6cb8b0fa9db948516b2b738fa1503cf0ef90e) - still crashes. Also tried latest Chrome Canary available on 19/03/2014 - crash is there.

We can provide the WinDbg memory dump if it's of any help.

PS: sorry, this should be the answer to Rob W thread right above but I cannot add it there due to 0 reputation.